# Set SharePoint Profile Picture to "Only Me"

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I need to be able to configure SharePoint 2010 so the user profile picture and other properties, such as Name, etc to have a "Default Privacy Setting/Default Visibility" of "Only Me". What steps are required to accomplish this please?

Comment: Found answer, stackoverflow.com won't let me post the answer (as an answer) for another 4 hours because I'm a new member :( Basically I should have read the Policy Settings description before I asked the question!

Comment: Hi Joe, welcome to stackoverflow.  This is a very good question for [SharePoint StackExchange](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/) but it sounds like it would not be a good fit for stackoverflow since it does not involve programming.

Comment: Agreed, should have realized.

Answer (score 1):

In Central Administration -> Manage Service Applications -> User Profile Service Application -> Manage User Properties, select the Picture property -> Edit and change the Policy Setting to Optional and the Replicable checkbox to false, then the Default Privacy Setting can be set to Only Me etc.  The clue was in the Policy Settings description which I should have noticed when trying to change the Default Privacy Setting.